# How to Put date into input type date in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem with how to put date that i get from json data into date input, like i said i want to put it into input type date but the problem is when i console.log the date, its came out but its not cameout into field and still dd/mm/yyyy

mydate

```
{
  this.state.post2.map((h, i) => {
    if (
      `${h.username}` ===
      `${this.state.formData.username}`
    ) {
      return (
        <FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label htmlFor="middleName">
              Middle Name
            </Label>
            <Input
              onChange={this.handleForm}
              key={i}
              defaultValue={h.middleName}
              type="text"
              name="middleName"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Middle Name"
              required=""
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</Label>
            <Input
              onChange={this.handleForm}
              key={i}
              defaultValue={h.lastName}
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              required=""
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
            <Input
              onChange={this.handleForm}
              key={i}
              defaultValue={h.email}
              type="text"
              name="email"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Email"
              required=""
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label htmlFor="phone">Phone Number</Label>
            <Input
              onChange={this.handleForm}
              value={h.phone}
              type="text"
              name="phone"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              required=""
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="expiredDate">
              Expired Date
            </Label>
            <Input
              type="date"
              name="expiredDate"
              onChange={this.handleForm}
              defaultValue={new Date(h.expiredDate)}
              placeholder="date placeholder"
              min={moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

response in console.log

```
25-01-2021 07:00:00
```

i already try to console.log and it appear but not appear on field and still dd/mm/yyyy
how to change dd/mm/yyyy into date that i get ?

Comment: Can you show us what the Input component is?

Comment: any change on - new Date(h.expiredDate).toString() ?

Comment: the input commpoent in the UI is dd/mm/yyyy  and can select the date.

Comment: no change toString. still dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: No, I would like to see the code for **Input**, where does it come from? If you want to respond to someone you should use `@name`

Comment: @HMR do you mean handleFormChange? or what?

Comment: I mean `<Input`, where does that come from?

Comment: it comes from argon template bro . from react strap
```
import {
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardFooter,
    FormGroup,
    Form,
    Label,
    Media,
    Container,
    Row,
    Table,
    Input,
    Button,
    
  } from "reactstrap";
```

Comment: Having a quick look at the [documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/#Input-Types) does not show me a documented `defaultValue` property but that could be because it's badly documented, maybe you found the `defaultValue` property somewhere else?

Comment: Note that `new Date("25-01-2021 07:00:00")` will give you an invalid date. Not sure why you have a REST endpoint giving you anything but ISO dates but maybe have a talk with the person responsible of that endpoint.

Comment: Was this ever answered?  I am using react bootstrap and am having this exact problem.  As soon as I change a react bootstrap control to type="date" I can't set it's value with data from my JSON source.

Answer (score 2):

What about this `defaultValue={moment(new Date(h.expiredDate)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`
not sure about moment parameters.Need to check.

Comment: still dd/mm/yyyy in field. btw i use argon template

Comment: That is the correct way of setting `value` of `input` (lower case). But OP uses `Input` (upper case) and has difficulty telling us where Input comes from. Also OP sets defaultValue and that doesn't do anything with `input` (lower case) no matter if the format is correct or not.

Comment: @HMR it comes from reactstrap  and  if i use ```<input``` still dd/mm/yyy ,

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar maybe read my comment first before replying' input (lower case) does not have a property called defaultValue.

Comment: i already change ma bro. why i use defaultValue ? to edit the field. if i use value, the field cannt be edit. thats why i use defaultValue

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar You are using inputs that get value from props and have onChange so it suggests you use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). If the other inputs work then maybe check why your onChange is not setting the props correctly. Also; if you use value then at least you should see the correct initial value

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar If value works but defaultValue doesn't then I guess you have to take this up with  `reactstrap`